# how do you get all ptr records from the mx records with PHP?

Tags: php

The idea behind this question is many mail servers will simply reject or flag you as a spammer and if you don't want to end up in a RBL with your ip's blacklisted you need a PTR record. aka reverse dns or rdns .I have this idea in my mind and i'm wondering whether it is correct or not

First obtain all MX records via getmxrr() after that get all there ip addresses as only ip's can have a PTR record not hostnames i got that now i'm stuck in getting all the ptr records can't figure this out i'm scratching my head ....

```
$mx_records = array();
getmxrr("google.com",$mx_records,$mx_weight);
for($i = 0; $i < count($mx_records);$i++)
{
     $mxs[$mx_records[$i]] = $mx_weight[$i];
}
asort($mxs);
$records = array_keys($mxs);
for($i = 0; $i < count($records); $i++)
{
    $host = gethostbyname($records[$i]);
    echo $host;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

so what's the trick into getting ptr records ? i don't understand how dns_get_record($host,DNS_PTR); works first time using this function help....

Comment: MX records are used for the servers that receive mail for the domain. The blacklisting you're talking about is for the sending servers. These don't need to be related, and will often be different for large organizations.

Comment: go to the website viewdns.info under dns report type google.com in the "MX records have reverse DNS entries test" you'll see

26.4.251.142.in-addr.arpa <--> gm-in-f26.1e100.net.
26.12.177.108.in-addr.arpa <--> ua-in-f26.1e100.net.
26.186.233.64.in-addr.arpa <--> cb-in-f26.1e100.net.
26.202.85.209.in-addr.arpa <--> dg-in-f26.1e100.net.
26.184.233.64.in-addr.arpa <--> wa-in-f26.1e100.net.

i'm wondering how this is done

Comment: I don't see that input field.

Comment: Anyway, to do what you want, you first get the MX records. Then for each MX record, look up the A records. Then for each A record, look up the PTR record for the address.

Comment: Well i'm failing to lookup the mx A records dns_get_record() does not accept arrays as the first parameter so typing a bunch of dns_get_record statements is resource sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `gethostbyname()`, as it can only return one address. Use `gethostbynamel()`, which returns a list of all the addresses.

When looking up the PTR record, you need to reverse the IP and append ".IN-ADDR.ARPA". You can then use `dns_get_record`, and loop over the resulting records.

```
foreach($records as $mx)
{
    echo "MX: $mx<br>";
    $addrs = gethostbynamel($mx);
    foreach ($addrs as $addr) {
        echo "  IP: $addr<br>";
        $reverse = implode('.', array_reverse(explode('.', $addr))) . ".IN-ADDR.ARPA";
        $ptr_records = dns_get_record($reverse, DNS_PTR);
        $names = array_column($ptr_records, 'target');
        echo "    Names: " . implode(', ', $names) . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: aaaaah so that is the reason i was only getting 1 ptr record while i knews this was incorrect .I was indeed using gethostbyname() thank you (again) for the help